# IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve AudioTrack pointer for write()

Tags: android, android-service

I am using a third-party text-to-speech tool to make my app ADA compliant. I am using this service to speak text every time text needs to be dictated:

```
class TTSService : Service() {

private val ttsUtils = TTSUtils.getInstance(this)

private val voiceText = ttsUtils.voiceText
private lateinit var audioTrack:AudioTrack

override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {

}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    audioTrack = AudioTrack(
            AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE,
    IVTDefine.SAMPLE_RATE_16000,
    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
    71296,
    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM
    )


    if (ttsUtils.isEnabled) {
        ttsUtils.getEngineVoice()

        if (null == voiceText) {
            return START_STICKY
        }

        audioTrack.play()

        try {

            Thread(Runnable {

                voiceText.vtapiTextToBuffer(intent?.getStringExtra("TextToSpeak"), //Library method that turns text string into audioTrack of
                    object : VoiceTextListener {
                        override fun onReadBufferWithWordInfo(output: ByteArray?, outputSize: Int, wordInfo: MutableList<SyncWordInfo>?) {
                        }

                        override fun onReadBuffer(output: ByteArray?, outputSize: Int) {

                            if (outputSize > 0) {
                                val audioData = ByteBuffer.wrap(output)

                                audioTrack.write(audioData, audioData.remaining(), AudioTrack.WRITE_BLOCKING)
                            }
                        }

                        override fun onReadBufferWithMarkInfo(output: ByteArray?, outputSize: Int, markInfo: MutableList<SyncMarkInfo>?) {


                        }

                        override fun onError(error: String?) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Error: $error")
                        }

                    })

            }).start()

        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {

            e.printStackTrace()



        }
    }

    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()

    voiceText.vtapiStopBuffer()

    if (audioTrack.playState == AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING) {

        try {
            audioTrack.pause()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            AppLog.e(TAG, e.message!!)
        }
    }


    try {
        audioTrack.flush()
        audioTrack.release()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        AppLog.e(TAG, e.message!!)
    }


}
}
```

The service is always started with this method in another class:

```
 fun speakText(textToSpeak: String) {

    val i = Intent(mContext, TTSService::class.java)

    i.putExtra("TextToSpeak", textToSpeak)


    mContext.stopService(i)

    mContext.startService(i)

}
```

I'm getting the above error when audioTrack.write() is called in the service's runnable, but I don't know what the error means. How do I make sure it's retrieving the pointer?